# Why would users of an Arabic interface show an F pattern in eye tracking tests?

Tags: language, localization, eye-tracking, writing-direction

Why does eye tracking on the Arabic version of my interface show an **F-pattern** only 50% of the time? I had assumed it would show a **reversed F-pattern** because Arabic people read right to left.

Comment: The 'F' pattern is the tendency of the eyes to track from the top left of the page in a left to right reading culture.

Comment: Firstly, I assume 100% of participants were indeed Arabic readers, and not confused left-to-right readers? If so, is the layout of your right-to-left Arabic interface a mirror image of the left-to-right interface, in that the key elements (navigation etc) are also on the right? If not, focus is likely still drawn to the left. A screenshot would be useful.

Comment: You could put that as an answer Matt - I'd agree with you on the influence of other navigational elements.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's going to be really hard to respond to this question unless we can see a screenshot of what your interface or site currently looks like. However here are some reasons as to why you are not getting a 100% right to left F shaped pattern for your site:

- **Your interface might not be totally right justified** as explained by [this article](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/horizontal-attention-leans-left/) :

> Our usability studies in countries that read right-to-left found the
>   same general pattern of increased attention to a line's beginning.
>   Obviously, in those languages, the beginning would be the right side
>   of the text. Even so, we wouldn't necessarily find a mirror image of
>   the above chart from eyetracking studies carried out on, say, Arabic
>   or Hebrew sites.
>
> The reason is that sites in right-to-left languages don't always
>   employ a mirror image of traditional left-to-right layouts. See, for
>   example, the following screenshots from the Dubai newspaper Emarat Al
>   Youm and the Israeli newspaper Haaretz :
>
> [image]
>
> *Emarat Al Youm* is a true right-justified site. In contrast, Haaretz uses right-justified text, but still has a navigation bar to the left.
>   So, an eyetracking study's results for Haaretz might be more complex
>   than simply flipping the pattern we see on English-language sites.

- **You might have a strong visual indicator on the left which draw attention** . To quote this [excellent research paper on Visual reading patterns on Arabic interfaces.](http://www.scribd.com/doc/75303513/Visual-Reading-Patterns-on-Arabic-Interfaces-Insights-from-Eye-Tracking)

> Another interesting findings was that irrespective of the visual patterns or attention, visual
>   attention of all the subjects was directed to the image of
>   Masjid-u-Nabawiwhich can be interpreted as attention influenced by
>   the cultural impact of the object of interest on the users.
>
> [image]

- Another reason which is again mentioned in the [above mentioned article](http://www.scribd.com/doc/75303513/Visual-Reading-Patterns-on-Arabic-Interfaces-Insights-from-Eye-Tracking) is perhaps  **the influence of white space** as mentioned below

> Visual Patterns also showed how white spaces aided the users in reading
>   the text with least hindrance of the multimedia content. Figure 8
>   clearly shows a smoothreading pattern within areas of content and
>   longer sac-cades across white space that separates content areas
>   without any distractions in the reading

[image]

- Another interesting thing which is called out in the [article](http://www.scribd.com/doc/75303513/Visual-Reading-Patterns-on-Arabic-Interfaces-Insights-from-Eye-Tracking) is that **RTL languages don't exactly follow the standard F shaped reading pattern and often show a number of different reading patterns namely the Triangular and Zigzag pattern as shown below**:

> In a right-to-left layout, it was interesting to find z-shaped patterns
>   in which viewers start with text then examine the multimedia content at
>   points in time in which the audio accompanying the video or animation
>   or video emphasizes a point with tone. Other instances of switching
>   between text and multimedia would be when animation is detected
>   by foveal vision of viewers. Patterns showing brief examinations of
>   these areas are in line with the findings of [16] in which they have
>   shown that viewers struggle to ignore inter-face elements that are
>   animated and consequently exhibit increased cognitive effort in
>   concentrating on the text which is exhibited by intense fixation.
>
> Visual patterns of triangular shapes were  observed across the
>   eLearning interface. As shown in Figure 2 & 3 the subject’s attention
>   alternated between the navigation,text and multimedia
>
> [image]
>
> Another visual patterns found in the Arabic interfaces are zig-zag
>   patterns. In this patterns, the reader starts from the right and
>   continue to the left then a little down and back to the right before
>   starting the another horizontal movement to the left again, which may
>   be because of the difference in the direction of Arabic scripts. Figure
>   9 shows the zig-zag visual pattern observed in the advertising study

[image]

All of this said, Philip's answer is also spot on since there might be a number of users who are not right to left language users and hence might start their standard scanning pattern from left to right with a standard F shaped pattern.

Comment: oooh - wow - cool answer!

Comment: Your answer was really helpful :)

Answer (score 2):

The vast majority of websites are **designed for left-to-right (LTR)** languages, and so the layout of these is such that an F pattern is most common.

When websites localise for a right-to-left (RTL) language, they often **only change the text** areas, and not the layout of the entire site.

The result is that even people that read in a RTL language (such as Arabic or Hebrew), many of the sites they are **used to**, re-enforce a F pattern due to their LTR origins.

In addition, many RTL language speakers also spend a fair amount of time reading sites in other LTR languages (such as French or English), and this re-enforces the F pattern even more.

**TL;DR: There is a difference between the direction of the language and the direction of the design, and people often become used to the design direction regardless of the language direction.**

Answer (score 1):

It could be you've got some people in the sample who can read English and therefore spend a fair amount of time starting Top Left.

You could check this by going back to them (possibly) and asking them if they can read English